# Which blocks get to be checkpoints?

Tags: blockchain, security, attack, blockchain-fork, checkpoints

Which blocks get to be checkpoints, and why is one block chosen to be a checkpoint, rather than another block? And where can I find a list of checkpoint blocks?

Answer (score 6):

At least in Bitcoin Core, none. Checkpoints are legacy and will likely be removed at some point.

Checkpoints were originally introduced as a way to enable skipping of signatures in the historical chain, without being vulnerable to accepting an alternate history. That role has now been overtaken by the `assumevalid` concept (a block hash that is known to be good, but doesn't prevent accepting another chain).

Checkpoints have also been used as a heuristic to know what block headers are acceptable before validating an entire block. That role was removed with headers-first synchronization in 0.10. We now only download a block after we already know its proof of work and difficulty are acceptable.

They have also been used as a measure for validation progress (so Bitcoin-Qt can show a progress bar during validation). That role has been replaced with just statistics data that doesn't affect validation.

The only thing checkpoints still serve for is preventing a low-difficulty headers attack, where your node gets spammed by a large number of long, low difficulty chain branches, making it go out of memory. Due to the existing checkpoints (up to height 295000), this is a very costly attack already.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the list in [bitcoin source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/c091b99/src/chainparams.cpp#L150-L162).
These are the current checkpoints (from git revision `c091b99`):

```
    checkpointData = (CCheckpointData) {
        {
            { 11111, uint256S("0x0000000069e244f73d78e8fd29ba2fd2ed618bd6fa2ee92559f542fdb26e7c1d")},
            { 33333, uint256S("0x000000002dd5588a74784eaa7ab0507a18ad16a236e7b1ce69f00d7ddfb5d0a6")},
            { 74000, uint256S("0x0000000000573993a3c9e41ce34471c079dcf5f52a0e824a81e7f953b8661a20")},
            {105000, uint256S("0x00000000000291ce28027faea320c8d2b054b2e0fe44a773f3eefb151d6bdc97")},
            {134444, uint256S("0x00000000000005b12ffd4cd315cd34ffd4a594f430ac814c91184a0d42d2b0fe")},
            {168000, uint256S("0x000000000000099e61ea72015e79632f216fe6cb33d7899acb35b75c8303b763")},
            {193000, uint256S("0x000000000000059f452a5f7340de6682a977387c17010ff6e6c3bd83ca8b1317")},
            {210000, uint256S("0x000000000000048b95347e83192f69cf0366076336c639f9b7228e9ba171342e")},
            {216116, uint256S("0x00000000000001b4f4b433e81ee46494af945cf96014816a4e2370f11b23df4e")},
            {225430, uint256S("0x00000000000001c108384350f74090433e7fcf79a606b8e797f065b130575932")},
            {250000, uint256S("0x000000000000003887df1f29024b06fc2200b55f8af8f35453d7be294df2d214")},
            {279000, uint256S("0x0000000000000001ae8c72a0b0c301f67e3afca10e819efa9041e458e9bd7e40")},
            {295000, uint256S("0x00000000000000004d9b4ef50f0f9d686fd69db2e03af35a100370c64632a983")},
        }
    };
```

It doesn't really matter how they are chosen, but notice the [following comments](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/c091b99/src/chainparams.cpp#L65-L71) found in the source:

```
/**
 * What makes a good checkpoint block?
 * + Is surrounded by blocks with reasonable timestamps
 *   (no blocks before with a timestamp after, none after with
 *    timestamp before)
 * + Contains no strange transactions
 */
```

Anyway, as long as they are inserted at regular intervals everything is fine. [This answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/1065/132) gives a hint at what is their purpose.