# Can the Bitcoin protocol be configured to *never* rollback after a certain block?

Tags: blockchain, security, blockchain-fork

Is it possible to hard code a block and its block hash into the client so that the block chain will never diverge from the main chain past that block?

My thought is that this will improve confidence for long term investors that their transactions are "safe" and can't be rolled back without consensus of the network (a.k.a 51% of the clients have that block as hard coded and can't be rolled back)

- Is this a reasonable idea?
- Has it been discussed before?
- Is it already implemented in some form?

Comment: Hmm, it appears this feature is implemented as "checkpoints" http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3115/1878

Comment: Yeah, post this comment as an answer and accept it in 2 days.

Comment: @ripper234 I voted to close. FYI I didn't delete the question because I want it to act as a signpost to that earlier Q

Comment: Good call, you have my vote. I don't believe in deleting questions.

Comment: @ripper234 Yea, me too. I dislike that aspect of stackoverflow.com's culture.  They are heavy handed on the deletes.

Comment: Close != Delete.

Comment: @StephenGornick - I agree.. though many highly upvoted questions have been deleted after a close.  See SO's meta.  I think some people are farming for rep or a badge or something.